# how to add record as last row of table (informix query)

Tags: sql, informix, multiple-select-query

i can select last record by this query

```
select first 1 idt from table1 order by id desc;
```

but i want to add a record ( id ++) to end of table in informix

Comment: Note that tables don't have 'ends' — the data is not ordered (they're sets of rows).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a [`SERIAL` column](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqlr.doc/ids_sqr_138.htm) in Informix.  This is a column that automatically increments when you add a new value.

So, the table should be defined as:

```
create table table1 (
    id serial primary key,
    . . .
);
```

Then when you do an insert, leave out the `id`:

```
insert into table1 ( . . . )  -- all but id
    values ( . . . );
```

The `id` will be automatically incremented and inserted with the data.

Comment: @alwaystudent: If you follow the instructions given by Gordon, it does work.  As an alternative, you can include the serial column in the column list, and specify the value 0 for it, in which case, the next unused serial number will be allocated (and you get told which one was allocated, slightly indirectly.  Or you can choose a value (call it V) and it will be used — as long as it doesn't violate the unique constraint.  When you do that, if the previous highest serial value was smaller than V, then the next value (that will be allocated using 0) will be set to V+1.